# os.MkdirAll() fails when creating nested directories

Tags: go

I have an `output/` directory.  When the directory to be created is

`prefix := "output/2021-11-12.19.51.50.047614/2011-12"`

`os.MkdirAll(prefix, 0644)` fails.  When it is

`prefix := "output/2021-11-12.19.51.50.047614"`

it works.

Why can't `os.MkdirAll()` create nested directories?  That's its purpose.  Is this a bug?

Comment: What does the error say? You’re not giving yourself permission to traverse into the directory, so I’m guessing it’s a permission denied error?

Comment: That was it. Changing permissions to 0755 worked.  The error messages I got were EACESS and ENOENT.  Not very intuitive at all.  I'll accept your answer if you make your comment answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mode` argument to `os.MkdirAll` *must* include some executable (`111`) bits.

In general, the `mode` argument to `os.MkdirAll` *should be* `0777`, at least on Unix-like systems.  In some cases, it should be `0700`.  (For the same reason, newly created files should be made with `0666`, not `0644`; sometimes `0600` is appropriate.)

The Go runtime passes the mode down to the OS-level calls.  On Unix-like systems, where the permissions actually make sense,<sup>1</sup> the bits that you provide are then modified by *clearing* any bits set in the current [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting.  It's this umask that should take away group and other write permissions, resulting in the eventual `0755` permissions—unless, that is, the user wants to take away more permissions (resulting in, say, `0750` or `0700`) or fewer (resulting in, say, `0775`).

Remember that the three groups of three bits represent read (`r`), write (`w`), and execute (`x`) permissions: `7` is `rwx`, `6` is `rw-`, `5` is `r-x`, and so on.  So `0777` represents `rwxrwxrwx`.

Unix-like systems require execute permission to name a file within a directory, so if you don't give yourself execute permission, you can no longer work with the directory.

---

<sup>1</sup>On systems with ACLs, user permissions make some sense and "other" might be reasonable as the default, but "group" is ill-defined.  Systems that do offer ACLs usually have a lot finer granularity than the simple `rwx` controls anyway, though.

Comment: I was expecting `os.MkdirAll()` to work like `mkdir -p`, but that's not the case.

Comment: The recursive / inner calls *could* use mode 0777 as `mkdir -p` does, but it makes more sense to use the provided mode in case the program really is intended to be extra-secure (ie in case it uses 0700). I would therefore argue instead that `mkdir -p` is wrong here: the `-m` argument you supply to it should apply recursively.